# There are 6 li elements inside my ul , I just want all li to break into 2 row when screen size bellow 430

Tags: html, css

There are 6 list item inside my `ul`, I am making a navigation menu. So I want to break down all 6 list items to two row(each row will have 3 list items) when screen size is bellow 430px.

I have added the code here

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

nav {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #616161;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

ul {
  display: table-row;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.x {
  display: none;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.d {
  color: #ccc;
}

@media (max-width: 430px) {
  
  nav {
    font-size: .8em;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    display: fluid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="start"><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
    <li class="end"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

please help me out, Thanks

Comment: `display: fluid;` is invalid!!

Comment: You might find a [Flexbox Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) helpful. Here's a [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084735/924299).

Answer (score 0):

I added flexbox to your `ul` when the breakpoint hits. As for the list-items, the `-2px` from this line accounts for the `2px` of border you're using.

```css
width: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);
```

If you look at the other answer as of this moment, you'll see the unevenness in item alignment.

[image]

To fix this, I also added the following rule:

```css
  nav ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  }
```

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

nav {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #616161;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

ul {
  display: table-row;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.x {
  display: none;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.d {
  color: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 430px) {
  
  nav {
    font-size: .8em;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 2px);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

  nav ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="start"><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
    <li class="end"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4wxt5s0/)

Comment: @malihasultana No problem. If you’re happy with my answer, I’d be grateful if you could select it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `flexbox` will be good for you:

With `li{flex: 1 0 15%;}` and in `@media` using : `flex: 1 0 25%;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;`

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/13xq84ay/1/)

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

nav {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  flex: 1 0 15%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #616161;
  padding: 10px 0;
}


.x {
  display: none;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.d {
  color: #ccc;
}

@media (max-width: 430px) {
  nav {
    font-size: .8em;
  }
  ul{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  nav ul li {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li class="start"><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
    <li class="end"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just try to create to css stylesheets: one for when javascript in the header detects screen size over 430 and one when below.